# flex as3 air get video and wireless adapters model and driver version

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

i am using as3, flex and air to build an application that needs to access desktop's video and wireless adapter information. i need the model name and driver version for both. i can get the MAC address from wireless adapter using the following code, just not the model or its version:

```
var networkInfo:NetworkInfo = NetworkInfo.networkInfo; 
var interfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = networkInfo.findInterfaces();
if( interfaces != null ) 
{ 
    for each ( var interfaceObj:NetworkInterface in interfaces ) 
    { 
        var dsc_mac_address:String = interfaceObj.hardwareAddress; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will be exposed via AIR; but if available you can write a Native Extension to access this info.

Comment: If `displayName` or `name` don't fit to your needs, I'm afraid it's not possible...

Comment: if i run ipconfig /all in windows cmd console i see the description of the wireless adapter, which happens to be the name i want. it's right next to its MAC address. how come air can't just grab the description? what am i missing?